# The user provider must return a UserInterface object, SYmfony 4 login error

Tags: symfony, symfony4

Guys I'm new to Symfony 4,

This is my security.yaml and my intention is to log in loading user from database

```
security:
   encoders:
       App\Entity\Login: 
          algorithm: bcrypt

providers:
    db_provider:
        entity:
            class: App\Entity\Login
            property: username

firewalls:
    dev:
        pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
        security: false
    main:
        provider: db_provider
        anonymous: ~
        form_login:
            login_path: login
            check_path: login
            default_target_path: postlogin
```

And this is my entity

```
class Login
{
/**
 * @ORM\Id()
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue()
 * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
 */
private $id;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
 */
private $username;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
 */
private $email;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
 */
private $password;

public function getId()
{
    return $this->id;
}

public function getUsername(): ?string
{
    return $this->username;
}

public function setUsername(string $username): self
{
    $this->username = $username;

    return $this;
}

public function getEmail(): ?string
{
    return $this->email;
}

public function setEmail(string $email): self
{
    $this->email = $email;

    return $this;
}

public function getPassword(): ?string
{
    return $this->password;
}

public function setPassword(string $password): self
{
    $this->password = $password;

    return $this;
}
```

}

And this is the full error

Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Exception\AuthenticationServiceException: The user provider must return a UserInterface object. in C:\xampp\htdocs\Auth\vendor\symfony\security\Core\Authentication\Provider\DaoAuthenticationProvider.php:85 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\Auth\vendor\symfony\http-foundation\Session\Storage\NativeSessionStorage.php(142): session_start() #1 C:\xampp\htdocs\Auth\vendor\symfony\http-foundation\Session\Storage\NativeSessionStorage.php(299): Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Session\Storage\NativeSessionStorage->start() #2 C:\xampp\htdocs\Auth\vendor\symfony\http-foundation\Session\Session.php(249): Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Session\Storage\NativeSessionStorage->getBag('attributes') #3 C:\xampp\htdocs\Auth\vendor\symfony\http-foundation\Session\Session.php(271): Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Session\Session->getBag('attributes') #4 C:\xampp\htdocs\Auth\vendor\symfony\http-foundation\Session\Session.php(73): Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Session\Session->getAttributeBag() #5 C:\xampp\htdocs\Auth\vendor\symfony\security\Http\Firewall\ContextListener.php(88): Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Session\Session->get('_security_main') #6 C:\xampp\htdocs\Auth\vendor\symfony\security-bundle\Debug\WrappedListener.php(46): Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Firewall\ContextListener->handle(Object(Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Event\GetResponseEvent)) #7 C:\xampp\htdocs\Auth\vendor\symfony\security-bundle\Debug\TraceableFirewallListener.php(35): Symfony\Bundle\SecurityBundle\Debug\WrappedListener->handle(Object(Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Event\GetResponseEvent)) #8 C:\xampp\htdocs\Auth\vendor\symfony\security\Http\Firewall.php(56): Symfony\Bundle\SecurityBundle\Debug\TraceableFirewallListener->handleRequest(Object(Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Event\GetResponseEvent), Object(Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Argument\RewindableGenerator)) #9 C:\xampp\htdocs\Auth\vendor\symfony\security-bundle\EventListener\FirewallListener.php(48): Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Firewall->onKernelRequest(Object(Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Event\GetResponseEvent)) #10 [internal function]: Symfony\Bundle\SecurityBundle\EventListener\FirewallListener->onKernelRequest(Object(Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Event\GetResponseEvent), 'kernel.request', Object(Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Debug\TraceableEventDispatcher)) #11 C:\xampp\htdocs\Auth\vendor\symfony\event-dispatcher\Debug\WrappedListener.php(104): call_user_func(Array, Object(Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Event\GetResponseEvent), 'kernel.request', Object(Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Debug\TraceableEventDispatcher)) #12 C:\xampp\htdocs\Auth\vendor\symfony\event-dispatcher\EventDispatcher.php(212): Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\Debug\WrappedListener->__invoke(Object(Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Event\GetResponseEvent), 'kernel.request', Object(Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventDispatcher)) #13 C:\xampp\htdocs\Auth\vendor\symfony\event-dispatcher\EventDispatcher.php(44): Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventDispatcher->doDispatch(Array, 'kernel.request', Object(Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Event\GetResponseEvent)) #14 C:\xampp\htdocs\Auth\vendor\symfony\event-dispatcher\Debug\TraceableEventDispatcher.php(139): Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventDispatcher->dispatch('kernel.request', Object(Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Event\GetResponseEvent)) #15 C:\xampp\htdocs\Auth\vendor\symfony\http-kernel\HttpKernel.php(125): Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\Debug\TraceableEventDispatcher->dispatch('kernel.request', Object(Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Event\GetResponseEvent)) #16 C:\xampp\htdocs\Auth\vendor\symfony\http-kernel\HttpKernel.php(66): Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernel->handleRaw(Object(Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request), 1) #17 C:\xampp\htdocs\Auth\vendor\symfony\http-kernel\Kernel.php(190): Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernel->handle(Object(Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request), 1, true) #18 C:\xampp\htdocs\Auth\public\index.php(37): Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Kernel->handle(Object(Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request)) #19 {main}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your "login" entity must implement UserInterface or AdvancedUserInterface

like:

```
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\AdvancedUserInterface;

class User implements AdvancedUserInterface, \Serializable
{
....
}
```

Comment: Keep in mind that AdvancedUserInterface  is deprecated for future Symfony versions. https://symfony.com/blog/new-in-symfony-4-1-deprecated-the-advanceduserinterface